# How to not crop last letter when using overflow:hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I jave the following snippet...

```css
.container {
    width:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:grey;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
lfhukglisdufhglreiuhgldsfhujglsdfjhgreiluhgeliruhgsdlfhujgluirhg
</div>
```

Is there a way to set overflow:hidden so that it doesn't display half a letter at the end? Is this a job for javascript instead?

Comment: How about this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgXPvZ ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also fix the `height` to only contain one line then add `overflow-wrap: break-word;`<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)</sup> so the last letter will simply wrap if it cannot be displayed fully:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height:1.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
  font-size: 40px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  lfhukglisdufhglreiuhgldsfhujglsdfjhgreiluhgeliruhgsdlfhujgluirhg
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, very simple. Is there a way to center the text within the grey div?

Comment: @fightstarr20 you mean horizontally?

Comment: Yes, in your example solution it is hard aligned to the left. I wanted to try and center it

Comment: @fightstarr20 simply add `text-align:center`